# Coreplot Bargraph--How to add layers

Tags: iphone

How to add layers in coreplot(Bargraph)

Answer (score 0):

"How to add layers in coreplot(Bargraph)" is an incomplete question. There are many kinds of "layers" that can be added to a core plot. text-layer, animation-layer etc. 
Try to reformat your question so that we can be of help.

Also, see a good description on bar plot [here](http://codejunkster.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/core-plot-2-bar-plot/)